# Currying method vs passing arrow function as a prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, currying, prop

In react a couple of ways of passing a parameter to an event handler or callback are encountered:

```
onClick={(e) => handler1(parameter)}
```

And

```
onClick={handler2(parameter)}
```

Where handler2 is usually declared as the component method:

```
handler2 = (parameter) => (e) => { ... }
```

Which syntax is better and why? (My guess is that does not matter)
Which do you personally prefer and Why?

Comment: with the first syntax, handler1 will not get the event, also a new function is being created on every render

Comment: Isn’t a new function being created on render in either case?